# "Dynamic" background for select element

Tags: html, css

I have the below select element:

```
<select id="P0_LANGUAGE">
    <option value="en">
        English
    </option>
    <option selected="selected" value="hu">
        Hungarian
    </option>
</select>
```

I can customize the select options as follows:

```
select option[value="en"] {
   background-image: url('eng-flag.png');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   padding-left: 25px;
   margin-bottom: 2px; 
}

select option[value="hu"] {
   background-image: url('hun-flag.png');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   padding-left: 25px;
   margin-bottom: 2px; 
}
```

This is fine, but I would also like to customize the main select element, so it shows the appropriate background of the selected option. But how could I achieve this?

Comment: The appearance of `<select>` elements rely on the underlying OS. There are some parts that can't be styled in any browsers and others that only work in some. A quick search for "style html select element" should net you lots of articles that discuss the issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try Like This

```
 background: #0088cc url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/hopstarter/flag-borderless/24/China-icon.png) no-repeat 90% center;
```

See This Fork 
https://jsfiddle.net/3pg81hjm/

Comment: Sorry, I guess you misunderstood my question. The option elements are fine, they have the desired styling (background). Let me explain this in a different way:The above is a language selector with two values: English, Hungarian.
When the select list is dropped down I can see the flags in the options. But the main select element does not show any of the flags. Does that make sense?

Comment: Oho Sorry For This I Cant Understand Your Previously Question Now   i Am Doing Your task